# AWS Free Tier Ending,How to make the resources reserved , rather than paying pay-as-you-go prices

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been using AWS Free Tier for a year now.It is expiring in a week's time. 
I'm trying to figure out how to make my currently running resources in the FREE Tier to be billed under reserved resources rather than pay-as-you-go service rates from next month when my Free tier ends.
I'm planning to reserve the resources I'm using for another year under heavy utilization.

Answer (score 1):

Just purchase reserved instances for the region, availability zone, and instance size you require. The new pricing will automatically be applied to your existing instance.

As far as the instance itself, there is *nothing* different between on-demand and reserved instances. Reserved instance pricing is *strictly* a pricing change, no more.